# Writing to a serial port in C in linux: differences between canonical and non-canonical methods

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, serial-port, canonical-form

Is there difference in code for writing to a serial port in C using **canonical** or **non-canonical** method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, there is a major difference.

The parameters of the communication port need to be modified to be transferring 'raw' or 'cooked' characters.

'raw' transfers every char, exactly as it is received.

'cooked' makes the I/O module handle control characters, back space, etc

Suggest starting by reading the MAN page for `tcgetattr()` and reading about (and understanding) all the related functions.

The functions are all part of the `termios` family of functions.

Comment: Thanks! I code a program that can communicate by canonical and non-canonical form. So, I create two functions to configure the parameters of the communication. Do you think that is good way to do that?

Comment: @JoseMarquesJunior,  your plan sounds good.  I would add another element to be preformed first, read/save the original characteristics of the interface using: `tcgetattr()`.  Before exiting the program, restore the original characteristics using: `tcsetattr()`.